# Filter out unset mysqli_query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to dynamically set some sql's based on variable values..

So I if i have

```
$somevariable = "somevalue" I set some $sql and $a1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1)
$somevariable2 = "somevalue2" I set some $sql2 and $a2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2)
```

and so on..

Now I want to run these queries and if any of them is FALSE i want to rollback

So here is what I have done..

```
mysqli_autocommit($con, FALSE);
if ($a1 and $a2 and $a3 and $a4 and $a5 and $a6)
{
mysqli_commit($con);
}
else
{
mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

Now my problem is $a can be any number and also any number in between also might not be there like $a1 and $a7 only or something like that.

So if I say ($a1 and $a2 and $a3 and $a4 and $a5 and $a6) it does not do commit because one of the variables is not there.

If i give ($a1 or $a2 or $a3 or $a4 or $a5 or $a6) it runs only the first query and does commit.

So how can I give as many variables as I have set and filter out the unset variables before I give 'and' for commit

I have tried

```
$tmp = array($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6,$a7,$a8,$a9,$a10); 
$filtered = array_filter($tmp); 
$one = implode("and", $filtered)
if ($one)
{
mysqli_commit($con);
}
else
{
mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

but it wont work either.. any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a loop? Each iteration performs the next query, checks the result, and if it failed it rolls back and exits the loop with `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use explicit variables for each interaction unless you want them for later.  You can use `[]` to append the result to the array so that you aren't leaving unassigned members, and use [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to evaluate.

```
function bool_and($a,$b) { return $a and $b; }
$result_array = array();
$result_array[] = mysqli_query($con, $sql1)
$result_array[] = mysqli_query($con, $sql2)
$result_array[] = mysqli_query($con, $sql7)

if (array_reduce($result_array,"bool_and",true))
{
    mysqli_commit($con);
}
else
{
    mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I have done wrong, but I cant get this code to work, every time it gives me rollback. The only thing i have changed is the lower case 'a' in array definition.

Comment: That was my copy/paste fail - I left out the `return` in the first line